# ¿Qué está pasando con mi app de dibujo?

Tags: javascript, html, html5, canvas

soy noob en Javascript, y el primer programa que estoy haciendo es una simple app de dibujo con el canvas de HTML, hasta ahora todo íba bien con mi código, pero cuando agregué una barra para modificar el tamaño del grosor del pincel se arruinó el progreso :'( cada que le doy click a la barra, el pincel pinta en la esquina superior del canvas sin pedirlo, ¿cómo corrijo eso?, mi código de HTML para la barra va así:

```
<input type="range" min="1" max="30" class="grosor_de_linea" onInput="grosor = this.value">
```

y el código de JS(Siento haberles puesto todo el código entero jaja):

```
document.addEventListener("mousemove", dibujar);
var areaDeDibujo = document.getElementById("area_de_dibujo");
var contexto = areaDeDibujo.getContext("2d");
contexto.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
contexto.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
var barraDeGrosor = document.getElementById("barra");
var x;
var y;
var color = "black";
var grosor = 10;

function posicionarPincelEnMouse(e) {
  x = e.offsetX;
  y = e.offsetY;
};

function dibujar(e) {
  if (e.buttons !== 1) {
    return;
  }

  contexto.beginPath();
  contexto.strokeStyle = color;
  contexto.lineWidth = grosor;
  contexto.lineCap = 'round';
  contexto.moveTo(x, y);
  posicionarPincelEnMouse(e);
  contexto.lineTo(x, y);
  contexto.stroke();
  contexto.closePath();
};

function cambiarColor(element) {
  color = element.style.background;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Primero un consejo: evita incluir eventos dentro de la misma etiqueta, quitando `onInput` de la siguiente línea:

```
<input type="range" min="1" max="30" class="grosor_de_linea" onInput="grosor = this.value">
```

Desde Javascript asignas el evento obteniendo el rango por su clase:

```
document.querySelector('.grosor_de_linea').addEventListener('click', funcion(e) {
    grosor = this.value;
});
```

Esto te ayudará a tener un HTML más legible y facilitará mantenimiento y depuración de tus scripts al tener toda la lógica en un mismo lugar.

Ahora, para resolver el problema, como estás escuchando clics en el documento, necesitas analizar si el clic se produjo al modificar el campo tipo `range`:

```
function dibujar(e) {
  if (e.buttons !== 1) {
    return;
  }
  // Analizar si el evento se disparó al modificar rango
  // ¿El elemento que disparó el evento tiene la clase "grosor_de_linea"?
  if(e.target.classList.contains('grosor_de_linea')) {
      // Evitar comportamiento normal del evento y salir de la función
      e.preventDefault();
      return;
  }

  contexto.beginPath();
  contexto.strokeStyle = color;
  contexto.lineWidth = grosor;
  contexto.lineCap = 'round';
  contexto.moveTo(x, y);
  posicionarPincelEnMouse(e);
  contexto.lineTo(x, y);
  contexto.stroke();
  contexto.closePath();
};
```

O, mejor aún, para evitar analizar cualquier otra posibilidad, asegúrate de dibujar solo si el clic fue en el área de dibujo:

```
function dibujar(e) {
  if (e.buttons !== 1) {
    return;
  }
  // ¿El elemento no es areaDibujo ni su descendiente?
  if(e.target != areaDibujo && !areaDibujo.contains(e.target)) {
      // Evitar comportamiento normal del evento y salir de la función
      e.preventDefault();
      return;
  }

  contexto.beginPath();
  contexto.strokeStyle = color;
  contexto.lineWidth = grosor;
  contexto.lineCap = 'round';
  contexto.moveTo(x, y);
  posicionarPincelEnMouse(e);
  contexto.lineTo(x, y);
  contexto.stroke();
  contexto.closePath();
};
```